# Logic to auto generate alphabet groups

Tags: javascript, reactjs, logic, grouping, reducers

I have a React App app with a Dictionary section that contains words and their meanings.

At the moment consists of a Navbar alphabetically, A, B, C, D etc etc etc all the way to Z and example if you click on C then it scrolls down to the the C section and displays all the C words.

The Navbar is static with an array containing ['A', 'B'...] all the way to 'Z' i, however the sections is automatically generated (dynamically) based on the available words.

```
 let data = posts.reduce((r, e, index) => {

            let group = e.title[0];
            group.normalize("NFD").replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "");

            group.toUpperCase();

            group = findSectionLetter(group);

            if (!r[group]) r[group] = { group, children: [e] }
            else r[group].children.push(e);

            return r;

        }, {});
```

I then add the data to state using `setGroups(Object.entries(data));` and it would output an array eg `[ ... ["B", {children: [..wordlist..], group: "B"}....]` etc, which is perfect cause now I can loop through it and can with relative ease achieve [{A, {actor, adam, apple}}, {B, {blue, bob, bunny}] etc on my template.

So I wanna do similar with the Navbar, where the index list now have the whole alphabet eg A, B, C, D and some links don't work if the word with letter doesn't exist, and it will look funny to have letters missing, I want to dynamic generate based on whats available and group further depending on what is not available.. eg,

If words is "Adam, Bob, Charley" (A, B, C) and the following word is "George"  (meaning no E & F) it should create group C-G to avoid the navbar from looking too empty.

My plan was to match the index value, but I'm not sure if I'm looking in the right direction or not.

Any suggestions?

Comment: BTW, `normalize`, `replace` and `toUpperCase` won't mutate the original string. You need to reassign them to `group`

Comment: btw, `group.toUpperCase();` does not work without assignment. strings are immutable.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest precomputing your alphabet groups and pass that as the initial value to the posts reduction.

```js
const groups = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".split("").reduce(
  (groups, ch) => ({
    ...groups,
    [ch]: { children: [] }
  }),
  {}
);

console.log(groups);
```

Note: `normalize`, `replace`, and `toUpperCase` all return new strings, so they can be chained. This also assumes all `title` string values are at least 1 character in length.

```
let data = posts.reduce((r, e, index) => {
  const group = e.title[0]
    .normalize("NFD")
    .replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "")
    .toUpperCase();

  groupKey = findSectionLetter(group);

  r[groupKey].children.push(e); // <-- push into group array

  return r;
}, groups); // <-- initialize with groups already made
```

Answer (score 0):

Just initialise groups to have an entry for all letters. You should probably also make a "catch all" for any title that does not start with a letter. For instance "-" could be that catch all.

Also make the groups data structure a dictionary (plain object) in order to access the groups for a given letter in constant time, without the need to search in an array.

And as you then have all the entries from the start, you don't need `.reduce()` anymore. Instead a `for` loop can be enough to iterate over the posts in order to populate the groups.

```js
let groups = Object.fromEntries(Array.from("-ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", group => [
    group, 
    { children: [], group }
]));

// Sample data
let posts = [{title: "Astrophysics"}, {title: "Biology"},
             {title: "Chemistry"}, {title: "### Something else ###"}];

for (let e of posts) {
    let letter = e.title[0]
        .normalize("NFD").replace(/[^a-z]/gi, "-") // Anything that's not a Latin letter
        .toUpperCase();
    groups[letter].children.push(e);
}

groups = Object.entries(groups); // Optional: In case you prefer the array of pairs.

console.log(groups);
```